# open ldap installation on unix and managing it from gui

Tags: openldap

I want to install openldap on linux , create some users there and want to manage it from gui, later on want to connect it through hadoop box to authenticate users .Is there any way to do it as i need to do it quickly as this topic requires a lot of time.

I followed this article but after installing , i cant find the slap.conf file on the specified directory and is stuck there.

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_openldap_setup_server_client

Can somebody give me quick pointers, it would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of openldap in linux is well documented around the world. Just use your favorite search engine to find a tutorial for your specific linux distribution. The mentioned doc in howtoforge may be a little bit old. Nowadays there is normally no slapd.conf file but the configuration is stored in ldap itself. You have to do the basic configuration with ldapadd/ldapmodify commands and *.ldif files. Possibly you may want to read [here](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup).

Installation of an ldap server should not be done quick without thinking because it is relevant to your system's security!

As a graphical management tool, I am using [ldap-account-manager (LAM)](https://www.ldap-account-manager.org/lamcms/), which is web-based management.